# Why is the ufw firewall blocking my request when I have the port set to open?

Tags: networking, firewall, raspberrypi, ufw

bareosdir == 192.168.57.130 
sshLandingBay == 192.168.57.195 
bigPi == 192.168.57.196

On my router I ran:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w -  'port 9102 or port 9103'
```

When I do a backup that works for instance on from bareosdir to bigPi, I get:

```
12:07:57.624013 IP bigPi.jalfrezisimmersauce.com.9102 > bareosdir.jalfrezisimmersauce.com.39320: Flags [P.], seq 282:318, ack 1002, win 501, length 36
12:07:57.624166 IP bareosdir.jalfrezisimmersauce.com.39320 > bigPi.jalfrezisimmersauce.com.9102: Flags [P.], seq 1002:1053, ack 318, win 502, length 51
12:07:57.624313 IP bigPi.jalfrezisimmersauce.com.9102 > bareosdir.jalfrezisimmersauce.com.39320: Flags [.], ack 1053, win 501, length 0
12:07:57.624654 IP bigPi.jalfrezisimmersauce.com.55268 > bareosdir.jalfrezisimmersauce.com.9103: Flags [S], seq 3028865621, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3811050966 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

When I try to do one oon sshLandingBay, I get:

```
2:01:01.689401 IP bareosdir.jalfrezisimmersauce.com.39410 > sshLandingBay.jalfrezisimmersauce.com.9102: Flags [S], seq 3364306509, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

And on the sshLandingBay itself I get the following messages stating the the firewall has blocked the request, so it's getting through the router, but not the firewall on the sshLandingBay:

```
[1470801.998206] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=b8:27:eb:58:25:25:00:24:a5:d7:34:9b:08:00:45:00:00:34:79:75:40:00 SRC=192.168.57.130 DST=192.168.57.195 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=3
1093 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=39410 DPT=9102 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
pi@sshLandingBay:~ $ sudo ufw status
Status: active
```

And yet my ufw settings are the following:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
9102                       ALLOW       192.168.57.130
```

Why is my local firewall blocking the BareOS server's request?

Comment: If you turn off the firewall completely does it work?

Comment: UFW is just a front end for iptables. While UFW generated rules are difficult/annoying to follow, show us your iptables rule set, do `sudo iptables -xvnL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `iptables -xvnL` as suggested above and realized that the rules were not applied.

So I ran:

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

And then it worked, I guess that's the SQL `COMMIT` of `ufw`.